Compatibility Issue with torch_scatter
I use Torch 2.4.1, Torchvision 0.19.1, and CUDA 11.8 for my model. Torch-scatter 2.12, which I have already installed, is incompatible with these. How can I determine which version is suitable?
I want to use torch-scatter in this part of my code:
# collect information
point_dict = Dict(feat=torch_scatter.segment_csr(self.proj(point.feat)[indices], idx_ptr, reduce=self.reduce),

